# Associative property of addition - Binary operators

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The `associative property` of addition says that it does not matter how we group the addends when we add *3 or more numbers*. My question is, does addition **only** operate on **2 numbers at a time?**(binary operator)

I don't know if the term "binary operator" exists, I am new to algebra. If they exist, could you give me examples of binary operators?

Comment: Yes, addition of numbers is a binary operation, so it is only defined for two numbers. Associativity allows you to define it unambiguously for any finite number of addends without specifying the order in which you apply the operation.

Comment: Hi @Arturo Magidin, so can we say that addition is an operation that allows 3 or more operands but **only** the + operator *itself* is the one considered binary?

Comment: It depends on what you define and how.  Coming from universal algebra I view addition as a strictly binaty operation, and then you get a bunch of what are called "derived operations" that are defined in terms of addition. Among them are two ternary operations, which we could write as $f(a,b,c) = +(+(a,b),c)$ (writing $+(x,y)$ to mean apply the binary function $+$ to $x$ and $y$ to get what we usually write $x+y$): and $g(a,b,c)=+(a,+(b,c))$. The associative property tells you $f$ and $g$ are equal as functions. But this is the formalistic way of talking about, not the natural one; cf Quiaochu.

Comment: Very good @Arturo Magidin, now it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not agree with Arturo's comment. Everyone knows what addition of $n$ numbers means intuitively: for example, if I have $n$ sticks each of length $\ell_1, \ell_2, \dots \ell_n$ and I put them all in a line then I get a big stick of length $\ell_1 + \ell_2 + \dots + \ell_n$, and so forth. Addition is a perfectly well-defined $n$-ary operation for every $n$ and this is something we understand before anyone tells us anything about associativity.

The significance of associativity is that it lets us reduce all of these operations to a single binary operation $a + b$, because we can get the larger operations from it, e.g. ternary addition $\ell_1 + \ell_2 + \ell_3$ is either $\ell_1 + (\ell_2 + \ell_3)$ or $(\ell_1 + \ell_2) + \ell_3$. In terms of sticks this means I can put $n$ sticks together by putting them together in pairs and it doesn't matter how I do this.

It's convenient to do this reduction-to-the-binary-operation thing because it means we only have to talk about a binary operation instead of a whole family of $n$-ary operations which is in some sense redundant. But sometimes it's worth going all the way up to the whole family of $n$-ary operations to remind ourselves why things like associativity are supposed to be true in the first place.

Comment: Hi @Qiaochu Yuan, I have several questions. In your first paragraph you basically mean that the addition can have **several operands**, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Excellent. "*The significance of associativity is that it lets us reduce all of these operations to a single binary operation a+b, because we can get the larger operations from it*" - This means that even though there are several operands, at the end of the day **they are added 2 by 2**, right? @Qiaochu Yuan

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way people do it.

Comment: So, can we say that addition is a n-ary operation but **only** the + operator itself is the one considered to be *binary*? @Qiaochu Yuan

Comment: Yes, you could say that.

Comment: Good @Qiaochu Yuan, these comments were important to mark your answer like the best one

Comment: The multiplication operator (x) itself is **also** binary, right? @Qiaochu Yuan

Comment: Yes, all of the same considerations apply here.